# install-exec-hook No rule to make target

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, makefile, automake

I've a C project developed in Eclipse with Autotools, and everything compiled and worked well. That's the "original" *Makefile.am*

```
bin_PROGRAMS = MyProgram_@PACKAGE_VERSION@

MyProgram_@PACKAGE_VERSION@_SOURCES = \
    MyProgram.c

include_HEADERS =

MyProgram_@PACKAGE_VERSION@_CFLAGS = -Wall \
    -I$(top_srcdir)/src/include \
    -I$(top_srcdir) \
    -I$(prefix)/include

MyProgram_@PACKAGE_VERSION@_LDFLAGS = \
    -L$(prefix)/lib \
    -lLibrary1\
    -lLibrary2\
    -lLibraryN

AM_CFLAGS = @MyProgram_@PACKAGE_VERSION@_CFLAGS@
AM_LDFLAGS = @MyProgram_@PACKAGE_VERSION@_LIBS@

CLEANFILES = *~
```

Problems started when I would like to create a symlink to my binary at installation time.

Googling I've found that best way to do it is to add install-exec-hook rule to my *Makefile.am*, and fundamentally I've add this lines of code to the Makefile, as explained here https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html#Extending

```
install-exec-hook: \
    ln -s  $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/MyProgram_@PACKAGE_VERSION@ \
           $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/MyProgram
```

But when I run Make Targets -> Build -> install from Eclipse I get the error: *No rule to make target "ln" needed by "install-exec-hook"*

I've tried making things easier, just to test if I'm missing something, and so I've written

```
install-exec-hook: echo "TEST"
```

But I still got the same error. Spent few days looking for this problem on the web, but nothing helped me.

Hope anyone can do it, many thanks
Andrea

Comment: In a Makefile everything following the `:` is taken as a dependency. If you extend your lines with `\` the content of the next line is taken as well. Try to remove the `\` after your target and put the rule in the next line.

Comment: Mmm I don't understand what you're meaning: should I remove the ':' ?

Comment: Sorry, formatting was broken. Now again: In a Makefile everything following the `:` is taken as a dependency. If you extend your lines with ` \ ` the content of the next line is taken as well. Try to remove the ` \ `  after your target and put the command to be executed in the next line.

Comment: Many thanks @Gerhardh, that works